# How to refer to the Java Wireless Toolkit storage root in Ant?

Tags: java, ant, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm looking for a way to automatically get the Java Wireless Toolkit storage root (the directory where the JWT stores the file system of a mobile device simulator), in an Ant build file.

Is there a property file or an environment variable that the JWT stores that path?